# Wordpress plugin how to insert data of form fields generated dynamically into database

Tags: php, wordpress, insert, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am running a form which is posting data to database in such a way that every question field is having many options that are generated dynamically, the question query is working good but the option that are created dynamically(that query runs to 500) is not working.

front end and html structure:

```html
<input name="text" placeholder="Question text" type="text" id="text">
<input type="text" placeholder="text" name="option_text[]" class="fieldname">
<input type="number" placeholder="0" name="option_score[]" class="fieldtype">
```

jquery: which is functioning correctly

```
function abc(){

var fName = new Array();

jQuery('.fieldname').each(function(index, value){
       fName.push(jQuery(this).val());
})

var fType = new Array();

jQuery('.fieldtype').each(function(index, value){
       fType.push(jQuery(this).val());
})

jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: { action: 'savedataques', text: document.getElementById('text').value, textopt: fName, score: fType},              
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
alert('data');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The Php code: the data query is good but the dataop query runs int the error of blank page.

```
    function savedataques(){
    global $wpdb;
    
            $data = ($wpdb->insert('wp_dbquestions', array(
                        
                        'text'        => $_POST['text'],
                    )
            ));
    
 
 $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
            echo $lastid;
```

this is where the problem is:

```
$dataop = ($wpdb->insert('wp_questoptions', array(
                'question_id'        => $lastid
                'text'        => $_POST['textopt'],
                'score'        => $_POST['score'],
            )
    ));

        }
   
    exit;

die();
return true;
}
//
add_action('wp_ajax_savedataques', 'savedataques'); 
//add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_savedataques', 'savedataques');
```

Comment: `question_id` is this primary key for table?

Comment: it is primary for the questions table not of questoption table

Comment: the last code snippet is where the problem is

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: the error is 500 bad request blank page when i add the snippet for dataop variable `$dataop = ($wpdb->insert('wp_questoptions', array(
                'question_id'        => $lastid
                'text'        => $_POST['textopt'],
                'score'        => $_POST['score'],
            )
    ));`

Comment: That `exit`, `die`, and `return` in the "dataop" function, try to replace them with: `echo $wpdb->insert_id; exit;`.

Comment: please see the posted answer its solved @Sally

Comment: Alright then. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution:
just need to apply a foreach on all the dynamically generated options

```
    $i=0;
    $optiontext = $_POST['textopt'];
    foreach($optiontext as $key => $val ){

        $score = $_POST['score'][$i];
        $textopt = $_POST['textopt'][$i];
        $i++;
```

then the query:

```
        $data = ($wpdb->insert('wp_questoptions', array(
                    'question_id' =>  $lastid,
                    'text'        => $textopt,
                    'score'        => $score,
                )
        ));
```

done